# Getting mongodb primary node from crashed replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication

Hi i have three mongo servers.,
10.0.0.1, 
10.0.0.2, 
10.0.0.3,

I configured replica set between these three.,
All was working fine.,
because of server crash now all went wrong.
10.0.0.1 - this one showing "secondary",
10.0.0.2 - this one showing "unknown",
10.0.0.3 - this one showing "unknown",

how to reconfigure replication;
I need either one should be a primary.,
means atleast i need one server as primary. how to get this.,

Comment: Seems like the servers can't see each other. Try to connect from each machine to each other machine.

Comment: Connection between each server is working. still have same issue.

Comment: Let me get that straight: you can connect from A to B and C using the mongo shell and the same goes for B to A and C and for C to A and B? What state do the different servers state they are in?

Comment: Can you post the `rs.status()` and tell us on which node you ran the `rs.status()`? Is there anything in the logs? What was the crash, and which node crashed? `Unknown` is a state for when members have *never* communicated, so I think something besides (in additon to?) a network problem is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself. did some R&D. Basically i was not able get **primary** from either of these servers. But one server was **secondary**. so what i did was,

1.

> Shutdown **other servers** by running **db.shutdownServer()** on **"Unknown"** servers.

2.

> Deleted all data from **dbpath** folder (Inside Files not Folder) on these 2 servers.

3

> Start mongo servers on both servers. This makes these mongo to be in STARTUP2 Status

This procedure gave me one **Primary** and recentlty restarted *STARTUP2*

> I didn't touch Secondary server. that is 10.0.0.1 in my case.